# simpy source code request superclass

Tags: simpy

I was reading through the simpy source code, and I found that for some reason, `Request` is a subclass of the `Put` class. Is there a reason for this? I thought a request was a request to get something out of a resource, not to put something into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea/abstraction behind this is, that Resource has a "shelf for user tokens".  If a user wants to use the resource, they tries to *put* their token into the resource.  They uses the resource until they removes the token.

If the shelf is already full, new users have to wait until they can place their tokens in it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @stefan, I was confused by the get/put difference between a resource.request() and a normal get event. I have used the simulation in which i do `resource.get()` and `resource.put()` without the context manager, in which case `resource.get()` seems to allow me to get something out of the resource (and it creates a `Get()` event?) I found the last example in the docs on this page to also seem to indicate that `put()` puts something into the resource and `get()` gets something out of it:
https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/resources.html

Comment: Also, I ran into this problem because I was trying to access a `Get()` event when it is created and add a callback to it. When you do `resource.get()`, it seem that it just adds this to the get queue (or the put queue for the resource?) without materializing the get event first. How would you add a callback to the get event? Do you have to access it by saying `resource.put_queue[-1].callbacks.append(xxx)`? You can't assign the get event to a variable first?